why we don't get equal number of negative and positive complex exponentials for the DTFS of a discrete time periodic signal?
When we compute the Discrete time Fourier series of a discrete time periodic signal , why don't we get the same number of negative complex exponentials and positive complex exponentials ?
Even though the magnitude spectrum is periodic throughout , if you take just the fundamental period , why the magnitude graph is not symmetric with respect to y axis  for some discrete time periodic signals ?

Did Hilmar answer your question? If so, please check it off as complete to close this out. Thanks and welcome to DSP.SE!


why don't we get the same number of negative complex exponentials and positive complex exponentials

But we do. We get an infinite number of positive and negative complex exponentials, i.e. $X[k]$ is well defined for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

the magnitude spectrum is periodic throughout

Exactly. Specifically
$$X[k] = X[k + mN] \forall m \in \mathbb{Z}$$
where $N$ is the DFT length.

why the magnitude graph is not symmetric with respect to y

But it is. It really depends on how you draw it. Since the DFT is periodic in $N$, any $N$ consecutive values will completely describe the entire DFT. The choice of which $N$ points to use is somewhat arbitrary and you can choose whatever suits your specific application best. The "fundamental period" simply chooses $[0,N-1]$ but you can also do $[-N/2,N/2-1]$, $[-3,N-4]$, etc. There is nothing "fundamental" about the so called fundamental period. It's just a convention that's convenient in some cases and less so in others. You don't have to stick with it, if it's not a good choice for your task.
